# Calculo com Inputs em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
function IBUTG() {
    $tt = $('[name=tempo_trabalho]');
    $vt = $('[name=valor_ibutg_trabalho]');
    $td = $('[name=tempo_descanso]');
    $vd = $('[name=valor_ibutg_descanso]');

    $ibutg = (($tt * $vt) + ($td * $vd)) / 60;

    $('[name=ibutg_calculado]').val($ibutg);
}
```

Estou recebendo NaN ao executar essa função, oque pode ser? Os valores dos inputs estão no formato 99.9

Comment: Faltou o `.val()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faltou o `.val()` no final

```
function IBUTG() {
    $tt = parseFloat($('[name=tempo_trabalho]').val());
    $vt = parseFloat($('[name=valor_ibutg_trabalho]').val());
    $td = parseFloat($('[name=tempo_descanso]').val());
    $vd = parseFloat($('[name=valor_ibutg_descanso]').val());

    $ibutg = (($tt * $vt) + ($td * $vd)) / 60;

    $('[name=ibutg_calculado]').val($ibutg);
}
```

Comment: Aff que burro kkkk. Até usei o parseFloat mas não estava funcionando por ter esquecido o .val().

Comment: Se essa resposta resolveu seu problema não esqueça de marca-la como certa.

Comment: Vou marcar sim @PauloGustavo, só to esperando dar o tempo mínimo.